# How to resolve PlatformException with just_audio on Flutter Web after application restart?

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm encountering a `PlatformException` error when using the `just_audio` package in a Flutter Web application, specifically after restarting the application and attempting to play an alarm sound. The issue does not arise on the first initialization but consistently occurs after a restart and subsequent interactions with the alarm sound button.

**Error Message:**

```js
Error: PlatformException(error, 
Platform player c6106b09-058c-4a76-b240-2f55e11f6efd 
already exists, null, null)
```

**Issue Context:**
The error is triggered when I try to play an alarm sound after the application has been restarted. This is part of a timer application where users can select different sounds for different timer states (e.g., start, pause, end). The issue seems to be related to how the audio player instance is managed across application restarts.

**Code Snippet** (simplified to focus on the problematic part):

```dart
// timer_notifier.dart snippet
Future<void> playSound({required bool userTriggered}) async {
  try {
    final selectedSound = ref.watch(selectedSoundProvider.notifier).state;
    await _audioPlayer.setAsset(selectedSound.path);
    await _audioPlayer.play();
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error playing sound: $e');
  }
}

// settings_page.dart snippet (button triggering the sound)
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    await ref.read(timerNotifierProvider.notifier).playSoundWithUserInteraction();
  },
)
```

**I've attempted the following without resolving the issue:**

- Ensuring the `AudioPlayer` instance is properly disposed of before application restarts.
- Checking for existing player instances before creating a new one, which isn't straightforward with the `just_audio` API.

I couldn't find a similar issue addressed in the `just_audio` documentation or on Stack Overflow.

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing the `Platform player already exists` error in this context?
2. Is there a recommended way to manage `AudioPlayer` instances in a Flutter Web application to avoid such errors?

Comment: It could be a bug in the package in which case you might want to submit a bug report.

Comment: @RyanHeise You're right, it's a bug right now I don't have the mentioned problem.